# Why is it "to start laughing" and not "to start to laugh"?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds, catenative-verbs

Why do we use:

> 1. *to start **laughing***

instead of,

> 2. *to start to **laugh***

And what is the construction *verb + (verb + ing)* called?

Comment: "to start to laugh" is also correct

Comment: @fluffy Yep, but it doesn't sound quite natural to me.

Comment: I started to laugh when I saw her hat. - -  sounds natural to me. :)

Comment: I would say "started to laugh" or "started laughing" is a lexical representation of inceptive aspect :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect

Comment: It's interesting to compare [start + watch](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started+watching%2Cstarted+to+watch&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstarted%20watching%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstarted%20to%20watch%3B%2Cc0) and [start + understand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started+understanding%2Cstarted+to+understand&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstarted%20understanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstarted%20to%20understand%3B%2Cc0), for example. Clearly the *second* verb is important.

Comment: is this a split infinitive?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No.

Answer (score 10):

To answer *Why is it **"to start laughing"** and not **"to start to laugh"**?*, I will point out that both alternatives are equally possible (but there are some minor points we should be aware of) by quoting a sub-entry from *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan. (Its main entry is about some verbs and adjectives that can be followed by either *-ing* forms or infinitives.)

> **299.10 *begin* and *start***
>   *Begin* and *start* can be followed by infinitives or *-ing* forms. Usually there is no important difference.
>   ​　　　*She **began playing / to play** the guitar when she was six.*
>   ​　　　*He **started talking / to talk** about golf, but everybody went out of the room.*
>   After progressive forms of *begin* and *start*, infinitives are preferred.
>   ​　　　***I'm beginning to learn*** karate. (NOT <del>I'm beginning learning karate.</del>)
>   Infinitives are also preferred with *understand*, *realise* and *know*.
>   ​　　　*I slowly **began to understand** how she felt.* (NOT ... <del>began understanding</del> ...)
>   ​　　　*He **started to realise** that if you wanted to eat you had to work.* (NOT ... <del>started realising</del> ...)

---

To answer *What is the construction 'verb + (verb + ing)' called?*, I will base my answer on chapter 13 section 4 (pages 214-6) of *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum, and answer that this construction is a **catenative construction** where the matrix verb (i.e. the main verb) is a **catenative verb**, and the complement is a **catenative complement**.

In our case, the catenative verb is *start* and the catenative complement of *to start to laugh* is a *to*-infinitival clause, and the catenative complement of *to start laughing* is a gerund-participial clause. (Please refer to section 3 in chapter 13 for more details on "the functions of non-finite clauses".)

According to the book, *the term 'catenative' is derived from the Latin word for "chain"*. To keep this answer short, I provide a link to page 215 on Google Books, along with a screenshot below. The page has a very good example of such a 'catenative' chain.

<sup>[page 215 of *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum](https://books.google.com/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA215)</sup>
[image: page 215 of *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum]

Comment: +1. :) Your next assignment, if you so choose to accept it, is to explain the the difference in usage between "begin" and "start" in these types of catenative constructions. :D -- Oh, be aware that *"After progressive forms of begin and start, infinitives are preferred"* is slightly, er, misleading. Aspectual verbs (e.g. "begin", "start") cannot themselves be in the -ing form when they have an -ing complement. CGEL page 1243-4, [57]. This is known as the "doubl-*ing* constraint".

Comment: Thanks (for both the vote and the assignment :-)! As far as I can tell, the difference between the two verbs, when exists, is more about one verb can't be used in the same meaning as the other (Swan lists three cases where *begin* is not possible: *We ought to start at six. The car won't start. The President's wife fired the gun to start the race.*) I can't really tell the difference in usage between "begin" and "start" in these types of catenative constructions. In the spirit of a language enthusiast, I searched and found this: https://is.muni.cz/th/383884/ff_b/Bachelor_Diploma_Thesis.txt.

Comment: From the thesis: "Catenative verbs begin and start followed by to-infinitive and –ing form of verbs listen, hear and sound are examined from the semantic point of view. [...] The analysis shows that start makes a specific claim for 'result', which means that it is suitable for contexts where an action, state or event must be perceived 'resultatively' – the result in the form of a goal. It refers to an initiation point of a process. [...] Generally, begin followed by to-infinitive form of selected verbs is more common than –ing form, while start is more common with –ing form."

Comment: Er, ya gotta be careful about the stuff found in undergraduate, and graduate, theses and papers, especially when they are written by EFL speakers. As to "start" vs "begin", er, that stuff is currently undergoing a so-called language change as to their usage in today's English, as is the common competition between infinitive and -ing as complements. :)

Answer (score 5):

*To start* is one of those verbs that can be followed by both gerund ([verb]-ing) and infinitive (to + [verb]). There is no difference in meaning whatsoever. This is also true for *to begin* and *to continue*.

That said, bear in mind that in continuous tenses the infinitive is used, i.e. "is starting to do something".

Comment: I suspect the *only* reason "in continuous tenses the infinitive is used" is because it sounds "awkward" to have two consecutive ***-ing*** verb forms. Effectively a matter of stylistic choice, rather than the application of a grammatical rule.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Quite so. The technical term for that "awkwardness" is *horror aequi*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I knew you'd used that term some while ago (more accurately, I knew you'd used ***a*** term, but on account of not remembering exactly what it was I couldn't search for it! :) Now I've got my clipboard on the case, I'm intrigued by [this definition](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/rodopi/lang/2006/00000059/00000001/art00011) which also mentions an (unnamed) *tendency (motivated by the quantity principle) for the variants **scarved** and **leaved** to be more strongly attracted to plural contexts than their rivals **scarfed** and **leafed**...*

Comment: ...which aren't words I'd be likely to use very often. But on reflection I think if I *did*, I probably *would* quite naturally "pluralise" those (adjectival) past tense verb forms as appropriate, without being consciously aware of it. Weird.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Me, too, and I never noticed it. That's fascinating

Comment: @StoneyB: That's one of the reasons I find ELL/ELU so interesting. It's nice to have a *name* for some aspect of usage that you are actually aware of (you just didn't know what to call it). But it's positively captivating (esp. at our age, as people interested in such matters) to discover we're falling into line with a principle we wen't even *aware* of for so long. In context, I'm more than happy to account myself a "learner".

Answer (score -2):

Here in started laughing : 'laughing' is a gerund.

To make it more clear a gerund is nothing but 'Verb+ing' form which is a noun.

Answer to your second question.

Verb+(Verb+ing) is nothing but verb+gerund --> it is nothing but verb+noun.

Here are the example that clears your confusion.

He likes playing cricket.

He hates smoking.

He masters gokarting.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes two expressions are used side by side. 1 to start with laughing ("with" was dropped later on) and 2 to start to laugh.

Comment: I think "Then the baby started with the crying" is a logical expression. Of course, today this is used in a shorter form, "with" and "the" are omitted. A number of verb constructions of the type verb + gerund can be explained by omission of a preposition before the gerund.