# What grammar constructions are used in "Do you want me to speak French?"

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitive-clauses

(Personal Background: I am a native speaker of English. As I have been learning French these past three months, I have been learning a lot about English grammar!)

In French, there is no grammar construction that matches the grammar construction used in the English sentence "Do you want me to speak French?". (But there is a French sentence that matches "Do you want to speak French?"). In order to say this sentence in French, you have to say "Do you want that I speak French?" (Note: That sentence, "Do you want that I speak French?", sounds very strange to my native ears. I say this because I don't want to give an incorrect idea to any English learners on this site.).

I am curious to know the grammar constructions used in this sentence. For example, what kind of word, grammatically, is "me" in this sentence? Is this sentence grammatically the same as "Do you want an apple?", or is the noun phrase "an apple" different than "me to speak French" (it certainly does seem different! "me to speak French" certainly doesn't sound like a noun!). If it is different, then what construction is being used?

Comment: Related: [Why is it “to start laughing” and not “to start to laugh”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/35156/3281) (Like tchrist's answer below, but with a little different terminology, "to speak French" is a non-finite clause, "Do you want me to speak French?" is a complex catenative construction, where "me" is a raised object. According to *[A Student's Introduction to English Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA221)*, "[It (a raised object)] is located syntactically in the matrix clause but belongs semantically in the catenative complement.")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What’s happening here in English is that you have an infinitive clause serving as a noun phrase.  Since it is acting a noun phrase, it can be used anywhere a noun can be used, including as the object of a verb, as the subject of a sentence, as the object of preposition, or (nearly) anywhere else a noun is called for.

This happens all the time.

- I want **to say something** in French.
- **To speak French** is **to love it.**
- It’s easy **to speak French**.

In those examples, the infinitive clause has no expressed subject. What’s happening in your case, however, is that the infinitive clause has its own distinct subject.

- I want ***Pierre* to speak** French.
- It’s easy **for *Pierre* to speak** French.

In English, the subject of non-finite verb clauses takes the object case when a pronoun is involved.

- I want ***him* to say something** in French.
- Pierre wants ***me* to say something** in French.
- It’s easy for ***him* to speak** French.

What you have stumbled upon here is that in most Romance languages, including not just [French](http://french.stackexchange.com) but also [Spanish](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), [Italian](http://italian.stackexchange.com), and dozens of others, infinitive clauses cannot take an expressed subject.  Instead, you need to make a tensed subordinate clause starting with *that*. When you do this in Romance, the subject is again in the subject case when it’s a pronoun, unlike the object case used for non-finite subjects in English.

Compare these:

- I want ***him* to say** something in French.
- Je veux **qu’*il* dise** quelque chose en français. (*French translation*)
- Quiero **que *él* diga** alguna cosa en francés. (*Spanish translation*)
- Quero **que *ele* diga** alguma coisa em francês. (*Portuguese translation*)

Since you are studying French, you will need to get used to making tensed subordinate clauses whenever you would in English have an infinitive clause with a subject.  Just to make it even more fun for you, these tensed subordinate clauses are often in the subjunctive mood, as shown above.

If, however, you were instead studying [Portuguese](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com), Galician, or Sardinian, then you **would** be allowed to used an infinitive clause with an expressed subject, provided it were not following a *that*, like when it’s the object of a preposition. Known as the [***personal infinitive***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitivo#Infinitivo_pessoal), this peculiar construction has an infinitive that’s actually inflected for number and person (but of course not for tense or mood), and it takes subject pronouns not object pronouns the way it does in English.  This makes it more convenient for English speakers first learning those languages.

But since you’re studying French not Portuguese, you don’t get to use that nifty construction, and so it’s necessary **that *you* should become accustomed** to saying things like this — rather than **for *you* to be become accustomed** to saying things like this.

Comment: wow, what a thorough answer, which not only gives me leads to understanding my own English language better, but also puts it into a context of other languages -- and helping me get used to the constructions I need in French. Thanks so, so much for taking the time to write this out!!

Answer (score 1):

**me** is a pronoun. It's the object of the sentence and is the accusative form of "I".

```
[Do]                      [you]          [want] [me]             [to speak]        [French]?
[Auxiliary interrogative] [noun-subject] [verb] [pronoun-object] [verb-infinitive] [noun]

[Do]                      [you]          [want] [an]         [apple]       [to take]         [home]?
[Auxiliary interrogative] [noun-subject] [verb] [i. article] [noun-object] [verb-infinitive] [noun]
```

You're correct that [me to speak French] isn't a noun, it's a [dependent clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause), used to add more information to the sentence.

In this case it restricts what you are providing, instead of offering all of "me", you're offering your ability to speak French.

Comment: *Me* is a pronoun, not a noun.

Comment: I would [argue](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42288/pronouns-a-word-class-or-a-subclass-of-nouns)  that [pronouns](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/nouns_different_types.htm) are [nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun). But I take your point