# What if `started` were used instead of `began` in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

The below sentence is from a fairy tale book.

> "Gretel **began** to cry."

I would like to know if using `started` instead of `began` there is also okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context the verbs *begin* and *start* mean the same thing. *Begin* is more formal than [*start*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/begin-or-start). So, they are interchangeable in most contexts.

There are some exceptions, however. For example, you *start* an engine.

Comment: "Also, after *start* infinitive is used whereas after *begin* - the gerund:" -- You might want to check out my answer to this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/why-is-it-to-start-laughing-and-not-to-start-to-laugh

Comment: @DamkerngT Thank you for the teaching. But, What you're saying is the gerund in addition to *infinitive* can be used after *begin* right? Not only the gerund.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Generally, yes, like I wrote about this in my old answer.