# Do you like going shopping?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the following question asking about? general or now?

> Do you like going shopping?

Is it mean *now* or in general. which one of the following is correct?

> - Do you like going shopping (now)?
> - Do you like going shopping (in general)?

Can I write it as following?

> - Do you like going shopping **tomorrow**?

**Update:**

Is the same apply on the following? or the verb will change the intended meaning time?

> - Do you **mind** going shopping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it "to start laughing" and not "to start to laugh"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/why-is-it-to-start-laughing-and-not-to-start-to-laugh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you like going shopping?

"Do you..." implies present tense, and "going shopping" refers to the process of shopping.  So "Do you like going shopping" would mean in the general sense, inquiring about a preference: "In general, do you currently enjoy the process of shopping?".

If you were accompanying someone on a shopping trip and asked that question, it would still refer to the general sense, but it might be interpreted in the context of that trip since that trip was happening in the present, as in "Do you enjoy shopping (in general), giving consideration to your experience right now?" (The person might generally dislike shopping but could be enjoying that specific event, so it might influence their attitude.)

> Do you like going shopping tomorrow?

Going shopping tomorrow is a future event.  You can't enjoy it in the present because it hasn't happened yet.  To inquire about someone's preference for engaging in a specific shopping event now or tomorrow, you need several changes to the sentence, such as "Would you like to go shopping now/tomorrow?"

"Would you like..." and "to go shopping" both refer to a future event ("now" is a future event in this case because you are not yet actually doing it; it means "starting very soon").

"Like" is about enjoyment.  If you are really asking about desire, "want" would be a more accurate word: "Do you want to go shopping now/tomorrow?"  The difference is subtle.  A masochist might enjoy shopping and for that reason, not want to.  For pretty much anyone else, there's no practical difference.  :-)

> Do you mind going shopping?

"Do you mind going shopping?" can have several meanings, with different implied timeframes.  It can be a different way to phrase "Do you like going shopping?".  The choice of "like" or "mind" frames the question with an implied preference, but it's asking about the same thing--a current preference.

It can also be a request.  A shopping trip is needed and you're asking the other person if they would be kind enough to do it.  This meaning refers to a future event rather than a current preference.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you like going shopping?

This is a general question. This works equally well: "Do you like shopping?"

> "Do you like going shopping tomorrow?"

Sorry, that does not work. "Would you like to go shopping tomorrow?"

Comment: And what about  _Do you like doing shopping?_ ?

Comment: Thank you, Is this is because the "like" verb, or because the clause structure and tense? e.g. "Do mind going shopping?" is general or now.

Comment: you do not need the word 'doing'.  I must/have to do the shopping. I am doing the shopping.  You are doing your shopping. It is present tense and it is actively what is happening now.

Comment: @Shannak are you asking for clarification?

Comment: @WillowRex If you don't mind.

Comment: I mean this [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shopping?q=shopping)

Comment: @Shannak I cannot explain grammar. The word 'do/doing' can be used in both the  present and future tenses.  Without a qualifier like 'will or will be', 'do/doing' is only present tense. I hope one of the grammar gurus can explain."Do you mind going shopping?" is both general and now and could also be a request to do the shopping.

Comment: @WillowRex Thank you very much, let me update the question by adding this example

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the general sense. It's asking if the addressee enjoys shopping in general. It could also be phrased as

> Do you like shopping?
>
> Do you like to go shopping?
>
> Do you like to shop?

It would *not* be correct to say

> Do you like going shopping tomorrow?

If you wanted to ask if the addressee would like to be shopping at that moment you would say

> Would you like to go shopping now?