# Should I say "started to" or "started by"?

Tags: grammar

I recently asked a [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21538/how-to-paste-text-after-each-line-matching-a-pattern) on the SE website [vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) and my question was [edited](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/21538/revisions) to correct my grammar mistakes.

I wrote:

> I started to yank the declaration of `var`.

And it was corrected to:

> I started by yanking the declaration of `var`.

To remove the technical content of this sentence, I guess we can replace it by:

> I started by copying the text of the file.

My question is: why should I use **started by** instead of **started to**?

According to this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55672/103300):

> *Begin* and *start* can be followed by infinitives or -ing forms.

So, I guess the way I wrote the sentence is correct. But there is no information about the "started by -ing" construction so I'm wondering if there is a subtility with this form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a (potentially big) *semantic* difference between...

> 1: *She started **to cry***
>    and
>    2: *She started **by crying***

Pragmatically we can assume that in #1 above, there must have been something that *caused* her to cry, but nothing about the words as presented gives any implication that her crying was part of any "defined sequence" of events. And it certainly says nothing about whether she might do anything else ***after*** starting to cry (apart from ***continuing*** to cry, obviously! :)

But the syntax of #2 very strongly implies that ***there was a [planned] sequence of actions*** [with some expected outcome] - the first of which was to cry. Usually (but not always), when someone *starts **by** doing something*, the implication is that they're consciously aware of the intended sequence that will follow. Perhaps if she didn't get what she wanted by crying, she might switch to ***cajoling*** or ***insisting***.

---

I've no idea what ***to yank the declaration of var*** means, so I can't say whether that's a credible construction or not with that particular "verb".

For example, it's quite possible to say *I started **by marrying** the boss's daughter* (as the first step in my plan to take over the company), but you can't really say *I started **to marry** the boss's daughter* in any context I can think of.

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers..A wonderful answer, as  always

Comment: "I've no idea what to yank the declaration of var means" - sounds like an action done while editing computer code; 'yank' being equivalent to 'pull', or more formally, 'remove' or 'delete'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sounds like you're as much in the dark as me (in which case arguably the best advice for OP is to forget about relatively minor ***syntactic*** issues, and concentrate on using actual ***vocabulary*** that's familiar to native speakers outside of the "geek programmer" context). But if it actually means something like "delete" (or indeed "retrieve" or similar) the question arises: *Can you "start" doing an action like that?* Or is it one of those actions like "marry", that aren't normally thought of as having any kind of "duration" once the act is initiated?

Comment: I am not in the dark at all, Fumblefingers. I am quite sure that 'yank the declaration of var' has a clear meaning to anyone who writes computer code for a living or out of interest. I quoted your remark starting 'I've no idea... ' at the start of my comment, then proceeded to address it.

Comment: I can easily see 'yank' meaning 'pull', which is a widely used verb meaning 'delete' or 'remove'.

Comment: The editor named Vi has a command called "yank," which is what most programs would call "copy."

Comment: Indeed, as Justin said, _yank_ means _copy_ that's why I had suggest another sentence: "I started by copying the text of the file." I'm sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you 'started **to do something**', you mean only that you commenced doing the named activity, and you are discussing nothing else. I started to shower (I went naked into the shower and turned on the water).

When you say that you 'started **by doing something**', you mean that the named activity was the first of a series of activities which altogether comprised a larger plan or process, which you have previously mentioned. I needed to get ready for my wedding. I started by showering (then I put on my underwear, suit, socks and shoes, and combed my hair).